# Laravel 5.3 doesn't trigger mutator

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem on this Laravel 5.3 Mutator. I can create the product without problems but during update, it doesn't trigger.

**My Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{


    public function setVisminAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['vismin'] = str_replace(",", "", $value );
    }

    public function setSpecialAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['special'] =  str_replace(",", "", $value);
    }

    public function setOutrightPriceAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['outright_price'] = str_replace(",", "", $value);
    }

    public function setConcessionPriceAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['concession_price'] = str_replace(",", "", $value);
    }

}
```

**My Update Code**

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->update( $request->all() );
```

Create works fine but update doesn't trigger the mutator.

**Request All**

[image]

Comment: Can you show the content of `$request->all()`?

Comment: I have updated the question with request all.

Comment: Do you have the fields you're updating in a `protected $fillable` property listed in your model?

Comment: This code will give you a lot of errors as I don't suppose your `Products` table contains a `_token` field.

Comment: Yes I have, `protected $fillable =  [
     'category_id', 'product_code', 'active', 'name', 'shortdesc',
        'desc','dimension', 'concession_price', 'outright_price', 'vismin', 'special', 'discount',
        'user_id', 'qty', 'created_at'
    ];`

Comment: I read this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12516 specially on the last part. I hope someone can give me better ways. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Do you need `->update()` here? Can't you use `->save()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this triggers now the mutator. I just found out that my accessor has an extra space. `public function getOutrightPriceAttribute($value){

        return number_format($value, 2, '.', ', ');
    }`. So I should use `$this->attributes['vismin'] = str_replace(", ", "", $value ); ` with space or remove the space in the accessor. It actually triggers during update. Thanks.